# How to best filter (descendent) elements by both name and class name?

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I need to get all DOM elements within DOM element `myRootElement`, that satisfy the following conditions:

1. have one of several element names (e.g. `div` or `blockquote`)
2. have one of several class names (e.g. `foo` or `bar`)

If it were just condition 1, I know I can write:

```
let elementsWithRightName = myRootElement.querySelectorAll("div, blockquote");
```

and then I can filter the result, like so:

```
let isOfNiceClass = (elem) => ["foo", "bar"].includes(elem.className);
let elementsOfInterest = [...elementsWithRightName].filter(isOfNiceClass);
```

but is there a better/most elegant/idiomatic way to apply both filters?

Comment: `myRootElement.querySelectorAll("div.foo, div.bar, blockquote.foo, blockquote.bar")` ?

Comment: @Kosh's hit the spot. Also, don't use `.includes()` with `.className`. Use [`.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches): ```['foo', 'bar'].some(c => elem.matches(`.${c}`))```.

Comment: @Kosh: Hmm. Now suppose I have 100 element names and 100 class names. Shall I construct the 10,000-phrase string?

Comment: @InSync: 1. Don't you mean `some()` rather than `every()`? 2. Are you making this suggestion for the case of a more complex rule regarding classes, that would require a regex? e.g. "class name starts with foo"? Or - is it because the class name itself is a comma-separated string?

Comment: 1. Yes, I did mean `.some()`. Fixed. 2. `.className` is [*space-separated*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className#value). You don't want to match `<div class="food">`, do you? For more complex cases, I'd say that depends.

Comment: @einpoklum, if you have 100x100 filter space, you've probably screwed up somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches):

```js
classNames.some(c => elem.matches(`.${c}`))
```

Or, with the new-ish [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)/[`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where):

```js
const tags = ['div', 'blockquote'];
const classes = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

const selector = `:is(${tags.join(', ')}):is(${classes.map(c => '.' + c).join(', ')})`;
// ':is(div, blockquote):is(.foo, .bar, .baz)'
const elementsOfInterest = myRootElement.querySelectorAll(selector);
```

For more complex cases, it depends. However, I'd say a CSS selector is probably the most efficient way to search for elements: browsers optimize it under the hood so we don't have to. I'm not sure about XPath though.

Comment: ... and then I use it like so `myRootElement.querySelectorAll(selector)`?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes.

Comment: So, I added that to the answer, since it makes it clearer (to me at least).